# VBA: Specifying a range using a string constant

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a simple function that counts the number of pipelines listed in a sheet codenamed LINES. The range in the sheet LINES where the lines will be listed is $A$2:$A$1048576 and I have named the range "LineList". I have made a module containing all my global constants that are hardcoded, so that I can alter them easily in the future. The name of the LineList range is one of those, defined as such:

```
Public Const LINELIST_RNG As String = "LineList"
```

My function is the following. For some reason this command is failing, due to the LINELIST_RNG being empty:

```
Function numLines() As Integer
    numLines = WorksheetFunction.CountA(LINES.Range(LINELIST_RNG))
End Function
```

However, if I hard-code the range name into this function, it works fine:

```
numLines = WorksheetFunction.CountA(LINES.Range("LineList"))
```

I am unsure why the .Range object cannot take LINELIST_RNG as an argument but will take "LineList".

Comment: Double check spelling? I can't see how that can happen, have you set a breakpoint verified the const's value ?

Comment: I do what you're proposing ALL THE TIME... Off the top of my head, I don't think that's why you're getting the error...

Comment: Also as that's a large range `as long` may be better as an integer  overflows beyond +32767

Comment: I've checked the spelling painstakingly. And what's more, I use the exact same methodology in other places in my code and those work completely fine. That being said, the places where I do that are just single cell ranges, whereas this range encompasses almost an entire column. Could that contribute to the issue?

Comment: I would not have thought so, at runtime the semantics of the value being in a string const should be exactly the same as when its a string literal

Comment: Is the `Const` value in the same module?

Comment: @AlexK. That's what I assumed, too. Thanks.

Comment: @PortlandRunner I have them both in the same module, yes. The error I get is Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed. When I hover over the .Range(LINELIST_RNG) part of the line, it tells me that LINELIST_RNG = Empty, even though the Public constant declaration is just the line above.

Comment: Try restarting your computer.

Comment: it does sound silly but try mattboy suggestion. Public consts in VBA sometimes do give a headache

Comment: Try renaming `LINELIST_RNG` to something else

Comment: @mattboy, I tried the restart and it's a no-go. I was pumped though, I thought that was it for sure.

Comment: @AlexK. Renaming did not seem to help either unfortunately. I can't understand the reason that A constant-defined string all of a sudden becomes empty when being used.

Answer (score 2):

The following code works fine:

```
Option Explicit

Public Const LINELIST_RNG As String = "LineList"

Public Sub test()

    Dim r1 As Range
    Dim r2 As Range

    Set r1 = Sheets(1).Range("LineList")
    Set r2 = Sheets(1).Range(LINELIST_RNG)

    MsgBox r1.Cells(1, 1).Value
    MsgBox r2.Cells(1, 1).Value

End Sub
```

so there must be something else going on in your code.  Turn on option explicit and it may point you in the right direction

Comment: I figured out that it had to do with the order of declarations, as I explained in my answer below, but I don't understand why really. Why is it that you cannot declare a constant below the declarations of other functions, even when it is not used by the functions above it, rather only the functions declared below it?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the problem arose from the order of declarations in my module. To give context, the declarations of

```
Public Const LINELIST_RNG As String = "LineList"
Function numLines() As Integer
```

were done after a list of Public Const and Function declarations and so they weren't working.

My module looked like:

```
Public Const ...
Public Const ...
Function blabla1 ...
Function blabla2 ...
Public Const LINELIST_RNG ...
Function numLines() As Integer ...
```

Now that I've moved all Public Const declarations to the beginning of the module, everything functions properly.